# fill fixed sized div with monospace font

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

Imagine having a string of characters and a HTML div-Element of a fixed size. How many characters of the string would fit into the div (without wrapping) by using a monospace font and a given fixed font-size?
Bonus: How can the font-size finally be slightly adjusted that the text takes really the whole width of the container.

JS

```
var s = "skjhfkjsdhjfksdhjkghskjgh...";
```

CSS

```
#c { width:267px; font-size:30px; font-family:monospace }
```

HTML

```
<div id="c"></div>
```

See this fiddle for an improvised approach, which works but is not that clean I guess. There might be better ways: https://jsfiddle.net/6et20853/1/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to `.getBoundingClientRect` an element that contains one monospace character to get the width of one char:

```js
oneCharWidth = document.querySelector('#testing').getBoundingClientRect().width;
console.log(oneCharWidth)
```

```html
<span id="testing" style="font-family: monospace">a</span>
```

If you want to check what font size will allow a string of text to fit a fixed-size container:

```js
var widthOfContainer = 400, // The width of the container in pixels
    textLength = "Hello world!".length, // The text to fit
    testElem = document.querySelector('#testing'),
    widthOfChar,
    fontSize = 100; // Our initial guess (must be exaggerated, otherwise optimal value won't be reached)

do {
  fontSize--;
  testElem.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
  widthOfChar = testElem.getBoundingClientRect().width;
} while (textLength * widthOfChar > widthOfContainer);

var container = document.querySelector('#container');
container.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';

testElem.parentNode.removeChild(testElem); // Remove #testing element
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 400px;
}

#testing {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Hello world!</div>
<span id="testing">a</span>
```